# Angular html table borders get ruined

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I dynamically generate angular html table. Actually, I generate several tables on page with different column numbers and sizes, and expandable editable cells is a must. Here is a simplified template I use:

```
<table>
    <colgroup ng-repeat="col in field.cols track by $index">
      <col width="{{col}}%" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead ng-hide="true"></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in field.rows track by $index" >
      <td ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index">
          <span class="text-container" ng-show="!cell.isEditing" >{{cell.text}}</span>
          <input type="text" ng-show="cell.isEditing" ng-model="cell.text" ng-blur="cell.isEditing = false" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and the very simplified directive is:

```
app.directive('tableField', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'views/table.html',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            field: '='
        },


        link: function($scope, $element, $attr){

            var init = function() {
                $scope.appendRow = function addRow() {
                    var newRow = [];
                    $scope.field.rows[0].forEach(function(col) {
                        newRow.push({'text': 'new'});
                    });
                    $scope.field.rows.push(newRow);
                };
                };
            };
            init();
        }
    };
}]);
```

this is how it looks before edits or page orientation change:

[image]

When I append a new row or edit cells and they expand, or rotate the device, the borders ruin - see the images:

[image]

[image]

Ideally I need to generate several tables on page with different column numbers and widths, with editable expandable cells. What shall I do to achieve proper result? I somehow need the table rows to update the row height upon any changes. Please help. I also could not find a library to do all I need.

Some part of the stylesheet:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

table > tbody > tr > td {
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

table .text-container {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

the rest regards colors and other stuff not influencing the table layout.

Comment: could you add your stylesheet

Comment: I cannot add the whole stylesheet as it is a big project and the stylesheet is too long. I will cut out the parts regarding the issue. You will not find these classes in the table, as i simplified it for readability, but I am sure you will see what you want to find there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up rewriting the table on flexboxes. Thus now it is not a `<table>` but a set of `<div>`s with flexbox styles. Though it looks nice and which is more works fine on all devices.